# Add font size in sitecore richtext editor

Tags: sitecore, sitecore6, sitecore7

I successfully change the font size selection of rich text editor of Sitecore by following [the instruction](http://www.galysoft.es/post/2013/09/19/Using-real-sizes-px-in-the-rich-text-editor-RTE-of-sitecore).

What I need to do now is to add a font size 60px in the selection. How and where can I change that?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To add font size in richtext control of sitecore, I modify the toolsFile.xml

```
<root>
    <tools name="MainToolbar" enabled="true">
        <tool name="RealFontSize" />
    </tools>
    <realFontSizes> 
        <item value="8px"></item>
        <item value="9px"></item>
        <item value="10px"></item>
        <item value="11px"></item>
        <item value="12px"></item>
        <item value="13px"></item>
        <item value="14px"></item>
        <item value="16px"></item>
        <item value="18px"></item>
        <item value="20px"></item>
        <item value="22px"></item>
        <item value="24px"></item>
        <item value="26px"></item>
        <item value="28px"></item>       
        <item value="32px"></item>
        <item value="48px"></item>
        <item value="60px"></item>
        <item value="72px"></item>
        </realFontSizes>
</root>
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a `Font Sizes` folder within the RTE profile. For the `Rich Text Full` profile you mentioned, it would be under the following path:

```
/sitecore/system/Settings/Html Editor Profiles/Rich Text Full/Font Sizes
```

Here you can create new items for any additional sizes you want. These would be based on the template `/sitecore/templates/System/Html Editor Profiles/Html Editor List Item`.

Comment: But adding fonts in this folder /sitecore/system/Settings/Html Editor Profiles/Rich Text Full/Font Sizes is not in pixel. It is numbered from 1 to 7. If I add 8, can I put the value as 60px?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make that list of real font sizes manageable within the core database, per profile, instead of "hardcoded" on the xml file, you must create your own custom EditorConfiguration class, inheriting from the one provided by sitecore and override the method SetupFontSizes as sitecore does not provide this functionality.
[This](https://github.com/galiana/SitecoreEditorConfigurator) is a sample project to show how to do it.